# Subversion import error 200030 (accessed from SCM in Xcode 3.2.2, OS X 10.6.3)

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, xcode3.2

I'm encountering the following error when attempting to (svn) import from within Xcode).

Import Failed
Error: 200030 (SQLite error) Description: no such table: rep_cache

This is a new repository.The svnserve process runs normally. Existing repositories work fine (import, commit, and export) from within Xcode. 
Neither MacPorts nor Fink are installed. The binaries in /usr/bin comes with Mac OS X 10.6.

I've googled but am unable to find others encountering the same issue.

Thanks in advance for any shared insights.

Comment: How did you create that repository? via svnadmin create ...which version of svn do you have installed ?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise. Yes, I did create the repository using 'svnadmin create'. And I've tried configuring the SCM in Xcode to access the repository using svn://, and also file://:. This new repository sits on the same hard disk volume as the Xcode's /Developer in the same MBP.

Strangely, there's no problem accessing repositories created when this same MBP was running Xcode 3.1 on OS X 10.6 works fine before the Xcode 3.1 was properly uninstalled and Xcode 3.2.2 installed.

Comment: One more thing:
svnserve --version reports 1.6.5 (r38866).

Comment: My apologies for the bump. I need your help, and appreciate any shared insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error. I found a [forum post](http://www.cumps.be/howto-installing-subversion-on-readynas-nv/#div-comment-1177) that solved the problem for me:

Edit <Repository>/db/fsfs.conf to uncomment the line

```
# enable-rep-sharing = false
```

Comment: Thanks. I disabled rep-sharing on all new repositories and was able to import.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error with a line I edited in config located in ~/.subversion

I had "build *.nib" (without quotes) on my global-ignores line, which should have been "build * .nib".  Don't know if that helps you, I'm a total noob with SVN, XCode, and programming in general.  But it did solve my issue adding the space there.  Good luck!

--Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for sharing.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue I'm facing, though I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem you faced.

- Chris